# System.InvalidCastException: Can’t write CLR type NodaTime.LocalDateTime with handler type TimestampHandler

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, clr, nodatime

All our code works locally on our computers (Tested on 8+ machines and also in new Docker Container). As soon as we deploy it to Azure, we keep getting the following error every time we're trying to fetch any data which contains dates.

Exception which is thrown:

> Can't write CLR type NodaTime.LocalDateTime with handler type TimestampHandler

The column have the type of `timestamp` in the database, which we need to be able to store it as `localdatetime`.

Server Stats:

- Linux
- .NET 7.0

Dependencies
[image]

Code examples:

The below code is to ensure mapping for NodaTime dates.

```
db.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), opt => {
        opt.UseNodaTime();
});
```

An example of retrieving the data, where the exception is thrown:

```
public async Task<List<Booking>> GetBookings(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    var fromDate = new LocalDateTime().FromLocalDateAndLocalTime(from, LocalTime.MinValue);
    var toDate = new LocalDateTime().FromLocalDateAndLocalTime(from, LocalTime.MaxValue);
    
    var bookings = _db.Rentals
        .Include(r => r.Product)
        .Where(r => r.Status != RentalStatus.Rejected)
        .Where(r => (r.PickupAt >= fromDate && 
                     r.PickupAt <= toDate || 
                    (r.ReturnAt >= fromDate && 
                     r.ReturnAt <= toDate)))
        .Select(r => new Booking() {
            Product = r.Product!,
            Rental = r,
            From = r.PickupAt,
            To = r.ReturnAt
        });

    return await bookings.ToListAsync();
}
```

Again, everything works until we deploy it. So we hope someone have suggestion about, what it could be. All other API calls are working as intended, it's only when it comes to this Date retrieval. If we spin it up locally and use the exact same database, it doesn't throw the Exception.

We're using `PostgreSQL 14.6` as database.

We've been following the documentation from:
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html?tabs=datasource

Where the suggested type of the column should be:
[image]

Comment: I don't know much about the npgsql integration, but using `LocalDateTime` for a timestamp doesn't sound right to me... I'd normally expect it to be `Instant`. (A `LocalDateTime` doesn't uniquely identify an instant in time - whereas `Instant` does, and that's what a timestamp is meant to be.) I've no idea why you'd only see the problem in some environments though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JonSkeet, but we have been following the following documentation: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html?tabs=datasource

Comment: Ah, right - it's Postgres's odd idea of what timestamp means. <sigh>